# Заполнение linkedlist объектами

Tags: java, коллекции

Доброго времени суток. Мучаюсь уже несколько часов. Есть класс Load:

```
public class Load {

    protected String teacher;
    protected int groupe;
    protected int numberOfHourses;
    protected String subject;
    protected String typeOfEmployment;
    protected int payment;


    public Load(){

    }

    public Load(String teacher, int groupe, int numberOfHourses, String subject, String typeOfEmployment, int payment) {
        this.teacher = teacher;
        this.groupe = groupe;
        this.numberOfHourses = numberOfHourses;
        this.subject = subject;
        this.typeOfEmployment = typeOfEmployment;
        this.payment = payment;
    }

    public String get(){
        return( this.teacher
                + ' ' + this.groupe
                + ' ' + this.numberOfHourses
                + ' ' + this.subject
                + ' ' + this.typeOfEmployment
                + ' ' + this.payment);
    }
}
```

И есть также класс Loads:

```
public class Loads {

    public List<Load> loadsList = new LinkedList<>();


    // Расчёт оплаты
    private int payment(String subject, String typeOfEmployment){

        int subj = 0;
        int tOE = 0;

        if ((subject.compareTo("English")) == 0)
            subj = 2;
        else if ((subject.compareTo("BigData")) == 0)
            subj = 3;
        else if ((subject.compareTo("OS")) == 0)
            subj = 2;
        else if ((subject.compareTo("OOP")) == 0)
            subj = 2;

        if ((typeOfEmployment.compareTo("Lecture")) == 0)
            tOE = 2;
        else if ((typeOfEmployment.compareTo("Practice")) == 0)
            tOE = 3;

        return (2*(subj+tOE));
    }

    // Заполнение коллекции
    public void addLoad(){

        Teachers teachersL = new Teachers();
        Groups groups = new Groups();
        ListIterator<Teacher> itr = teachersL.teachersList.listIterator();

        if (itr.hasNext()){
        Load load1 = new Load(teachersL.teachersList.get(0).getName(), groups.groupsList.get(0).number, 2, "English", "Lecture", payment("English", "Lecture"));

        Load load2 = new Load(teachersL.teachersList.get(1).getName(), groups.groupsList.get(1).number, 2, "BigData", "Lecture", payment("BigData", "Lecture"));

        Load load3 = new Load(teachersL.teachersList.get(2).getName(), groups.groupsList.get(1).number, 3, "OS", "Practice", payment("OS", "Practice"));

        Load load4 = new Load(teachersL.teachersList.get(3).getName(), groups.groupsList.get(2).number, 2, "OOP", "Lecture", payment("OOP", "Lecture"));

        Load load5 = new Load(teachersL.teachersList.get(4).getName(), groups.groupsList.get(3).number, 3, "OS", "Lecture", payment("OS", "Lecture"));

        Load load6 = new Load(teachersL.teachersList.get(5).getName(), groups.groupsList.get(1).number, 3, "BigData", "Practice", payment("BigData", "Practice"));



        loadsList.add(load1);
        loadsList.add(load2);
        loadsList.add(load3);
        loadsList.add(load4);
        loadsList.add(load5);
        loadsList.add(load6);

        }

    }
}
```

В классе `Loads` коллекция `linkedlist` должна заполняться объектами `Load`. В двух других классах заполнение работает, всё как нужно записывается в файл и считывается. Но здесь даже коллекция не заполняется (проверял через `size();` ). Как быть?

Comment: Пройдитесь по коду под отладчику, посмотрите в переменные, сложно сказать, с виду все правильно.

Comment: проверяйте итератор

Comment: Судя по всему, вы же только создали `teachersL`. Т.е. он по факту "пустой". Откуда же там данные для перебора возмутся?

Comment: @Chubatiy, В main`e я сначала вызываю метод WriteT, в нём идёт вызов метода из Teachers, который заполняет коллекцию в классе Teachers. Затем уже вызываю метод writeL, в котором заполняется loadsList. Но в writeT используется название экземпляра teachers. Из-за этого?

Comment: Всё решил проблему. Chubatiy навёл меня на мысль о проверке результатов при совпадении имён (вызове teachers из главного класса, вместо создания teachersL). Благодарю за помощь.